# Indexing with boolean arrays into multidimensional arrays using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, scipy

I am new to using numpy and one thing that I really don't understand is indexing arrays.

In the [tentative tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-d55e594d46b4f347c20efe1b4c65c92779f06268) there is this example:

```
>>> a = arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> b1 = array([False,True,True])             # first dim selection
>>> b2 = array([True,False,True,False])       # second dim selection
>>>
>>> a[b1,b2]                                  # a weird thing to do
array([ 4, 10])
```

I have no idea why it does that last thing. Can anyone explain that to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array consists of:

```
0  1  2  3
4  5  6  7
8  9 10 11
```

One way of indexing it would be using a list of integers, specifying which rows/columns to include:

```
>>> i1 = [1,2]
>>> i2 = [0,2]
>>> a[i1,i2]
array([ 4, 10])
```

Meaning: row 1 column 0, row 2 column 2

When you're using boolean indices, you're telling which rows/columns to include and which ones not to:

```
>>> b1 = [False,True,True]       # 0:no,  1:yes, 2:yes       ==> [1,2]
>>> b2 = [True,False,True,False] # 0:yes, 1:no,  2:yes, 3:no ==> [0,2]
```

As you can see, this is equivalent to the `i1` and `i2` shown above. Hence, `a[b1,b2]` will have the same result.

Note also that the operation above is only possible because both `b1` and `b2` have the same number of `True` values (so, they represent two arrays of the same length when expressed in the integer form).

Comment: +1 Here is a link for further reading, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html